# 2D to 3D segments conversion formula - from area difference

Tags: geometry

I have a shape - let's say a quadrilateral. ABCD

I am using this in a roofing application.

2 of the segments of this roof fascia - are not parallel with the ground so they are actually longer than they appear in 2D. (lets say AD and BC)

We know

- both surface areas (2D and in 3D)
- all segment lengths in 2D

I need to find the length of the 2 segments not parallel with the gound.

I know the area difference between 2D and 3D, I know that I need to apply that difference to only 2 of the segments, and it needs to be proportional with their length.

Any idea will be highly appreciated!

Edit:
To find the area, I use https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Polygon if needs to be known (Irregular Polygons).

Comment: If two sides are parallel to the ground, then the quadrilateral is a trapezoid, right?

Comment: This is a random example. A roof fascia can have more segments - the formula needs to work for all segments not parallel with the ground. So unfortunately, we dont know how many and what shape.

Comment: How come you know both surface areas but not the polygons side lengths ?  This is a very strange assumption.

Comment: @HosamHajjir I know the 2D segment dimensions and the slope. User will add the slope. From slope, there is formula to add a coefficient to the 2D area and get the 3D area.

Comment: What do you mean by slope ?  Which slope ? And what is that formula ? And what is the coefficient used to convert from 2D area to 3D area ? @alextoader

Comment: So the user will be able to define in the application the roof slope. Be it pitch, grade or angle. He can set a general pitch for the whole roof or individual inclines for each roof fascia. The coefficient results from applying the pitch to the 2D area. The formula is this: https://roofing-area-calculator.com/how-to-calculate-roof-area (is not that the website - that is just an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the 2D coordinates for the polygon or polygons that form the roof, as projected to a level ground plane (perpendicular to gravity, i.e. horizontal; usually called *run* in housebuilding).  You also know the actual area of the polygon, i.e. the actual area of the roof.

Mathematically, we simply need to assign $z$ coordinates to the polygon vertices, according to a chosen direction, and slope (pitch) $k$.  Finally, we need to adjust $k$ until the 3D polygon area matches the known actual roof area; that then gives us not only the correct slope $k$, but also the exact 3D edge lengths of the roof polygon.

---

The simplest generic case is a [trapezoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid), where two edges are parallel.  One of those parallel edges is the roof ridge, and another the gutter, and we assume these are level (perpendicular to gravity, i.e. horizontal).  These have the same length in 2D and 3D, because they're horizontal.

If we consider the side profile, the non-parallel edges form the hypotenuse of a right triangle, with the 2D length of the edge and the elevation between gutter and ridge as the sides of the right triangle.

This means that if $h$ is the vertical elevation from gutter to ridge (measured vertically; known as "*rise*"), and $\ell$ is the 2D length of either one of the two non-parallel edges of the trapezoidal roof (known as "*run*"), then the true 3D length of that non-parallel edge $L$ is
$$L = \sqrt{\ell^2 + h^2} \tag{1}\label{BtV1}$$

If the length of the roof ridge is $a$, the length of the gutter edge is $b$, and the 2D distance (*run*) between the two is $r$, then the 2D area of the trapezoid is
$$A_2 = \frac{a + b}{2} r \tag{2}\label{BtV2}$$
(Note that this also works for triangles, by setting either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.)

However, in 3D, the same right triangle applies, except this time to that gutter-ridge horizontal distance, or *run*, $r$.  In 3D, the true distance between the roof and the gutter is $R$,
$$R = \sqrt{r^2 + h^2} \tag{3}\label{BtV3}$$
and the 3D area of the trapezoid is therefore
$$A_3 = \frac{a + b}{2} \sqrt{r^2 + h^2} \tag{4}\label{BtV4}$$
where, again, $h$ is the "*rise*": vertical height difference between the roof and the gutter.

If we do know $A_3$, $a + b$, and $r$, we can trivially solve $h$:
$$h = \frac{\sqrt{ 4 A_3^2 - r^2 ( a + b )^2 }}{a + b} = \sqrt{\frac{4 A_3^2}{(a + b)^2} - r^2 } \tag{5}\label{BtV5}$$
The two sides are equivalent, use either one you find easier.  Then, the pitch $p$ (as measured in feet per feet, or inches per inches) is
$$p = \frac{h}{r} \tag{6}\label{BtV6}$$
On the other hand, if we know the pitch $p$ (as in feet per feet, or inches per inches), and the gutter-ridge *run* (measured horizontally, not along the roof) $r$, then
$$h = p r \tag{7}\label{BtV7}$$

In other words, if you know the pitch $p$ (as in feet per feet, or inches per inches) and the gutter-ridge run $r$ measured horizontally and not along the roof, and $\ell$ is the run length of an edge between the gutter and the ridge (also measured horizontally and not along the roog), then the true length $L$ of that rising edge of the roof is
$$L = \sqrt{\ell^2 + p^2 r^2} \tag{8}\label{BtV8}$$

All that may look complicated, and you might think you only need the last one, but I think realizing how useful $h$ (vertical rise between gutter and ridge) is even more important.  When you know two of $h$, pitch $p$, and gutter-ridge run (horizontal, not along the roof) $r$, you can calculate the third using $\eqref{BtV6}$ or $\eqref{BtV7}$ or $r = h / p$; and then the rest is easy using these.

Comment: Thanks Blabbo - great work. It looks complicated but I am sure it is easier than it looks.